# set date in create view

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a view in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I need to enter the current date as the date that the import was done.  Here is what I have:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @SQL as varchar(4000)
        --@CD as date

--set @CD = convert(varchar(30), cast(getdate() as date), 110)


    -- Insert statements for procedure here
set @SQL = 'CREATE VIEW vw_GCS_Export
    As
    select division, [primary image id],[Item Number], [Brand Name],[Marketing Description],
    [Colours]as Colors,[Live Date],[Sample Type],substring([FileName],charindex('+ CHAR(39) + '_' + CHAR(39) +',[FileName],1)+1,CHARINDEX('+ CHAR(39) + '.' + CHAR(39) +',[FileName],1)-5) as BatchID,
    '+ CHAR(39) + '670' + CHAR(39) +' as Status, [Primary image ID] + '+ CHAR(39) + '_P' + CHAR(39) +' as [Shot Name],
    Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Swatch/Variation],Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Alternate Shot],[UserName],' + CAST(convert(date,Sysdatetime(),110)as varchar(10)) + ' as [Import Date],
    Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Return Instructions],Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Rush Request]
    from Sheet1$'


EXEC (@SQL)
select * from vw_GCS_Export
```

When I get the results the field ImportDate is returned as 2008.  I was hoping for 04/01/2013 or something similar.  I just need to get the current date inserted into the field.

I have tried several cast and convert combinations and even a function that returns the current date and time but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date literals need to be surrounded by single quotes, so you need to modify your @SQL with escaped quotes surrounding the date expression:

```
select ''' + CAST(convert(date,Sysdatetime(),110)as varchar(10)) + ''' as [Import Date]'
```